# Is it possible to use CSS selectors without a list?

Tags: css-selectors, html-lists

I have the following classes:

```
.at-icon.at-icon {}
```

And I need to style each element (Social network icon), that uses those classes, like this:

```
.at-icon.at-icon:nth-child(even) { fill: red !important }
.at-icon.at-icon:nth-child(odd) { fill: blue !important }
```

So one element would be red, and the other one would be blue. They all appear like this currently:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuaaV.jpg)

And my HTML using the class is:
    Copy Link

The problem is: I don't have any `<li>` (List) in the `DOM`.
Unfortunately, this is all I can post here to reproduce my issue, as I'm using a third party tool, this one addthis.com

It's a free tool, you can use it for testing. I can't use it for testing as it would mean using my account resources and I might be going against their TOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

What you could do is find the nearest parents of these `<svg>` elements that are siblings of one another, from what I can tell from your screenshot, these could be the `<a>` elements with the class `at-share-btn` applied to them.

Then, use those elements to identify the even and odd instances.

```
.at-share-btn:nth-child(even) {
}

.at-share-btn:nth-child(odd) {
}
```

After that, using the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), target the `<svg>` elements within these `<a>` elements.

```
.at-share-btn:nth-child(even) .at-icon {
    fill: red !important;
}

.at-share-btn:nth-child(odd) .at-icon {
    fill: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: What class is this "at-share-btn"?

Comment: Please update your answer stating the use of "!important", I'll mark it as solved.